# Why will you float in free fall with 0 relative acceleration?

Tags: free-fall, galilean-relativity

Imagine you are in an elevator that is falling freely to the surface of the earth. You begin to float. However you and the elevator have equal acceleration. Why is it that you begin to float with respect to the elevator?

Comment: Because you and the elevator have equal acceleration.

Comment: @JohnRennie so shouldn't your feet remain on the floor of the elevator instead of floating?

Comment: You should remain stationary with respect to the elevator, yes. If it ever actually happened your body would expand as the gravitational compression is removed and this would propel you off the floor like a released spring.

Comment: @JohnRennie can we explain the floating with inertial concepts?

Comment: @JohnRennie can we say that as one suffers from weightlessness, he cannot apply enough force on the floor and so he floats...???

Comment: You don't begin to float unless you jump.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine you are in an elevator that is falling freely to the surface of the earth. You begin to float. However you and the elevator have equal acceleration. Why is it that you begin to float with respect to the elevator?

You do not really float, you simply travel at the same speed as the elevator.

Answer (score 1):

Your feet are touching the floor of elevator applying a force to keep you upright. Although this force doesn't immediately go/reduce to zero when the elevator stars to free fall, it becomes small so that applying even a small force/push with your feet will be enough to separate you from the floor and then it appears you are floating.

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is not wrong!

Comment: I will remove my downvote if you reword your answer like this — "... Although this force doesn't immediately go/reduce to zero when the elevator stars to free fall, it becomes small so that applying even a small force/push with our feet will be enough to separate us from the floor ..."